# Incorrect passive auth URL after changing WsFedPassiveMetadataUri

Tags: lync, lync-2013

I have been trying to enable passive authentication on Lync server 2013. Using the `Set-CsWebServiceConfiguration` I have set `UseWsFedPassiveAuth` to true as well as setting `WsFedPassiveMetadataUri` to the metadata URI of the ADFS server. However, I have later found out that the `WsFedPassiveMetadataUri` was incorrect (meaning the wrong ADFS server, the data in the .xml file itself were valid) and I had to replace it with a correct URI. However, after replacing it, the `https://.../PassiveAuth/PassiveAuth.aspx` link is still pointing to the old login page.

Is there some way how to "refresh" it? I tried restarting the Lync server, but that didn't help.

Thanks, any suggestion or hint is welcomed.

PS. when I manually modify the PassiveAuth.aspx file and I use `.Replace` method to replace the wrong login page domain to the correct one (so `.Replace("login-wrong.example.com", "login-correct.example.com")`), everything works as it should.